# チェックボックスを使用した表示/非表示の切り替え

Tags: javascript

Todoリストを作る上で、チェックボックスを使用した表示/非表示の切り替えを実装したいと考えております。

実装したい形としては以下です。

- タスクの状態によって表示/非表示を切り替えできる
- 選択されたラジオボタンに応じて、タスクの表示を切り替える
- 「作業中」選択時にタスクを新規追加した場合、タスクが表示される
- 「完了」選択時にタスクを新規追加した場合、タスクは表示されない（が、裏ではちゃんと追加されている）

現在以下のようなコードですが、以下のエラーが出ます。

```js
{
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const addTaskTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-trigger')[0];
    const addTaskTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-target')[0];
    const addTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-value')[0];
    const radioWork = document.getElementById('radio-work'); 
    const radioDone = document.getElementById('radio-done');
    let nextId = 0;
    const todos = [];

    //Taskとidを作成
    const addTask = (task, id, tableItem) => {
      const idSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      const taskSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      //タスク追加時にtodosにtodoを追加 
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      idSpanTd.innerText = id;
      taskSpanTd.innerText = task;
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(idSpanTd);
      tableItem.append(taskSpanTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
    };

    //Button要素を生成する
    const addButton = (tableItem, removeButton, createButton) => {
      const createButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      const removeButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      createButton.innerText = '作業中';
      removeButton.innerText = '削除';
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(createButtonTd);
      tableItem.append(removeButtonTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
      //生成したbutton要素を生成する
      createButtonTd.append(createButton);
      removeButtonTd.append(removeButton);
    };

    //追加ボタンをクリックした際にtd要素を追加する処理を行う
    addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const task = addTaskValue.value;
      const tableItem = document.createElement('tr');
      const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
      const createButton = document.createElement('button');
      addTask(task, nextId++, tableItem);
      addButton(tableItem, removeButton, createButton);
      addTaskValue.value = '';
      // //削除ボタンを押した時にタスクを削除する
      const deleteElement = (a) => {
        const tableTag = a.target.closest('tr');
        if (tableTag) tableTag.remove();
        updateId();
      }
      removeButton.addEventListener('click', deleteElement, false);

      //ボタンを押したら作業中、完了中と変わる
      createButton.addEventListener('click', (a) => {
        if (createButton.textContent === "作業中") {
          createButton.textContent = "完了";
          const doneParent = a.target.parentNode;
          doneParent.className = 'workDone';/*完了class*/
        } else {
          createButton.textContent = "作業中";
          const workParent = a.target.parentNode;
          workParent.className = 'work';/*作業中class*/
        }
      });
    })
    
    //todoの状態を管理
    const todo = [{task: 'taskSpanTd',status: '作業中'},{task: 'taskSpanTd',status: '完了'}]
    todos.push(todo);

    /*ラジオボタン作業中を押下時の処理*/
    radioDone.addEventListener('click', function () {
      let workTasks = document.getElementsByClassName('work');
      workTasks = Array.from(todo[0]);
      if (radioWork.checked.todo[0] === true) {
        workTasks.forEach(function (workTasks) {
          workTasks.style.display = "";
        })
      } else {
        workTasks.forEach(function (workTasks) {
          workTasks.style.display = "none";
        })
      }
    })

    // ラジオボタン完了押下時処理
    radioWork.addEventListener('click', function () {
      let doneTasks = document.getElementsByClassName('workDone');
      doneTasks = Array.from(todo[1]);
      if (radioDone.checked.todo[1] === true) {
        doneTasks.forEach(function (doneTasks) {
          doneTasks.style.display = "";
        })
      } else {
        doneTasks.forEach(function (doneTasks) {
        doneTasks.style.display = "none";
        })
      }
    })

    //　連番　再振り直し
    const updateId = () => {
      const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
      const taskList = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      nextId = 0;
      Array.from(taskList, tr => {
        tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent = nextId;
        nextId++
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Todoリスト</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Todoリスト</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="task" value="1" checked ="checked">全て
    <input type="radio" id="radio-work" name="task" value="2">作業中
    <input type="radio" id="radio-done" name="task" value="3">完了
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>コメント</th>
      <th>状態</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="addTask-target" id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
  <h2>新規タスクの追加</h2>
  <input class="addTask-value" type="text" />
  <button class="addTask-trigger" type="button">追加</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
main.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

todoに代入している配列番号を呼び出している形ですが、なぜか未定義となってしまいます。
スコープなどが関係しているのかと思い、オブジェクト内に入れてみましたが、解決出来ず。

お手数ですがご教示のほど、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず，エラーが出ている箇所ですが，

```js
      doneTasks = Array.from(todo[1]);
```

...ではなくてその次の行，

```js
      if (radioDone.checked.todo[1] === true) {
```

ですね．

では，radioDoneはなんでしょうか．

```js
const radioDone = document.getElementById('radio-done');
```

です．つまり，`input[type=radio]`です．`radioDone.checked`はその要素を選択しているかどうか(bool値)ですので，そのプロパティに`todo`は存在し得ません．

なので，まずはそのあたりから見直されてみればいかがでしょうか．